# How to create this XML using PHP SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:NetworkRequest xmlns:x="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <IpAddress>127.0.0.1</IpAddress>
</x:NetworkRequest>
```

I tried

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xmlns:x:NetworkRequest></xmlns:x:NetworkRequest>');
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:x','http://www.google.com');
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org');
$xml->addChild('Version','2.0.0');
$xml->addChild('IpAddress','127.0.0.1');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

and got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:NetworkRequest x="http://www.google.com" xsi="http://www.w3.org">
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <IpAddress>127.0.0.1</IpAddress>
</x:NetworkRequest>
```

`xmlns:` prefix is missing for `x="http://www.google.com"` and `xsi="http://www.w3.org`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code locally and it won't execute.

I got the following <s>error</s> warning:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]:
>   namespace error : Failed to parse QName 'xmlns:x:' in
>   C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 3

So, I have this lazy suggestion (seeing as the xml you are producing isn't that complex or needs modifying on the fly; I avoided SimpleXMLElement class altogether like this):

```
<?php

function getNetworkRequestXML($version, $ip_address) {
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:NetworkRequest xmlns:x="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
    <Version>'. $version .'</Version>
    <IpAddress>'. $ip_address .'</IpAddress>
</x:NetworkRequest>';
}

var_dump( getNetworkRequestXML('2.0.0', '127.0.0.1') );

?>
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:NetworkRequest xmlns:x="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org">
    <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    <IpAddress>127.0.0.1</IpAddress>
</x:NetworkRequest>
```